How to apply an adversarial attack recipe to a dataset?
I have a dataset of people lying and telling the truth about different opinions. I have all these attack recipes from github, so I tried a lot of different ways to apply the first attack recipe (a2t_yoo_2021) to my dataset and every time I get a different error. The furthest I've gotten is with this code:
import pandas as pd
from textattack.models.wrappers import HuggingFaceModelWrapper
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer
from textattack.attack_recipes import A2TYoo2021

# dataset
df = data_sensitive

# opinions
texts = df[['A', 'CL', 'E', 'GM', 'Pom']].agg(' '.join, axis=1).tolist()  
# opinion labels 
labels = df[['GT.A', 'GT.CL', 'GT.E', 'GT.GM', 'GT.Pom']].agg(' '.join, axis=1).tolist() 

# initializing the model
model_name = "distilbert-base-uncased"  
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

model_wrapper = HuggingFaceModelWrapper(model, tokenizer)

attack = A2TYoo2021.build(model_wrapper)

# apply attack to dataset
adversarial_examples = []
for i, text in enumerate(texts):
    attack_result = attack.attack([text], label=labels[i])  # Apply attack on each text with its label
    adversarial_examples.append(attack_result)

# Create a DataFrame with original and adversarial examples
adversarial_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': df['ID'],
    'original_text': texts,
    'adversarial_text': adversarial_examples
})

# Save the adversarial examples to a CSV file
adversarial_df.to_csv('adversarial_dataset.csv', index=False)


I expected a dataframe with the original opinions and the adversarial opinions (slightly changed).
This is the error I got:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 16
     13 model_wrapper = HuggingFaceModelWrapper(model, tokenizer)
     15 # Build the attack
---> 16 attack = A2TYoo2021.build(model_wrapper)
     18 # Apply attack to the dataset
     19 adversarial_examples = []

File c:\Users\20210295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\textattack\attack_recipes\a2t_yoo_2021.py:78, in A2TYoo2021.build(model_wrapper, mlm)
     69 #
     70 # Greedily swap words with "Word Importance Ranking".
     71 #
     73 max_len = getattr(model_wrapper, "max_length", None) or min(
     74     1024,
     75     model_wrapper.tokenizer.model_max_length,
     76     model_wrapper.model.config.max_position_embeddings - 2,
     77 )
---> 78 search_method = GreedyWordSwapWIR(
     79     wir_method="gradient", truncate_words_to=max_len
     80 )
     82 return Attack(goal_function, constraints, transformation, search_method)

TypeError: GreedyWordSwapWIR.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'truncate_words_to'
TextAttack Version: 0.3.10
c:\Users\20210295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\file_download.py:1142: FutureWarning: `resume_download` is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0.0. Downloads always resume when possible. If you want to force a new download, use `force_download=True`.
  warnings.warn(
Some weights of DistilBertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at distilbert-base-uncased and are newly initialized: ['pre_classifier.bias', 'pre_classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias', 'classifier.weight']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
textattack: Unknown if model of class <class 'transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_distilbert.DistilBertForSequenceClassification'> compatible with goal function <class 'textattack.goal_functions.classification.untargeted_classification.UntargetedClassification'>.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 24
     21 model_wrapper = HuggingFaceModelWrapper(model, tokenizer)
     23 # Build the attack
---> 24 attack = A2TYoo2021.build(model_wrapper)
     26 # Apply the attack to the dataset
     27 adversarial_examples = []

File c:\Users\20210295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\textattack\attack_recipes\a2t_yoo_2021.py:78, in A2TYoo2021.build(model_wrapper, mlm)
     69 #
     70 # Greedily swap words with "Word Importance Ranking".
     71 #
     73 max_len = getattr(model_wrapper, "max_length", None) or min(
     74     1024,
     75     model_wrapper.tokenizer.model_max_length,
     76     model_wrapper.model.config.max_position_embeddings - 2,
     77 )
---> 78 search_method = GreedyWordSwapWIR(
     79     wir_method="gradient", truncate_words_to=max_len
     80 )
     82 return Attack(goal_function, constraints, transformation, search_method)

TypeError: GreedyWordSwapWIR.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'truncate_words_to'
textattack: Unknown if model of class <class 'transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_distilbert.DistilBertForSequenceClassification'> compatible with goal function <class 'textattack.goal_functions.classification.untargeted_classification.UntargetedClassification'>.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 A2TYoo2021.build(model_wrapper)

File c:\Users\20210295\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\textattack\attack_recipes\a2t_yoo_2021.py:78, in A2TYoo2021.build(model_wrapper, mlm)
     69 #
     70 # Greedily swap words with "Word Importance Ranking".
     71 #
     73 max_len = getattr(model_wrapper, "max_length", None) or min(
     74     1024,
     75     model_wrapper.tokenizer.model_max_length,
     76     model_wrapper.model.config.max_position_embeddings - 2,
     77 )
---> 78 search_method = GreedyWordSwapWIR(
     79     wir_method="gradient", truncate_words_to=max_len
     80 )
     82 return Attack(goal_function, constraints, transformation, search_method)

TypeError: GreedyWordSwapWIR.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'truncate_words_to'

